# Choosing a tool to take off the front cassette

Tags: tools

My bicycle is Merida Crossway MD 40. It uses Shimano Altus derailleurs. The front cassette looks like this:

[image]

I measured the central circular element, that must be holding the whole construction. It looks like this:

[image]

What instrument should I buy to disassemble the front cassette from the bicycle? Does [this ebay item](http://www.ebay.com/itm/BBB-Lockout-Cassette-Lockring-Remover-Tool-BTL12-Bicycle-Bike-Cycle-Campagnolo-/141395671116?pt=UK_SportsLeisure_Cycling_BikeLocks_SR&hash=item20ebd6b84c) fit?

[image]

Comment: That is not a cassette.  Cassette is in the rear.  That is a crank and chain-rings.  Do you want to remove just the chain-ring or the whole assemble (pedal to pedal)?

Comment: @Blam Chain ring

Comment: That's completely the wrong tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell whether your crank is a classical design or something new and weird.  For the classical design you use a "crank puller".

[image]

or

[image]

These look sort of like what you show, but you notice the "barrel" is threaded.  You remove the bolt holding the crank on (using a standard "Allen" hex wrench) and then thread in the outer barrel of the puller, into the female threads surrounding the bolt head.  Turning the arm (or using a wrench on the inner part) then "pulls" the crank off.

Some cranks are "self pulling".  You leave in place the dust cover over the bolt, insert an Allen wrench into the hole in the dust cover, then unscrew the bolt against the dust cover.

If your crank is not the "classical" style then you will need whatever specific tools the manufacturer calls for.

Once the crank is off, of course, you may want to remove the "bottom bracket" cartridge.  There are about 6 different wrenches for this, for different styles.

[Park Tool has an excellent web site](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help) with instructions on how to do all this stuff.

Comment: Excellent answer for removing cranks, although you didn't mention removing the crank bolt with a hex wrench. He specified in a comment that he only wants to remove the chain rings.

Comment: @Mac - Quote: "You remove the bolt holding the crank on (using a standard "Allen" hex wrench)"

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

According to the website for your bike (http://2014.merida-bikes.com/en_int/bikes/cross/cross/2014/crossway-40-md-390.html), you have an SR Suntour XCM crankset.

The documentation for that crankset (http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/bike/chainwheels/XCM-XCM-T428-SQ-OCTA-4212.html) indicates it's compatible with this bottom bracket (http://www.jensonusa.com/Shimano-Octalink-BB-ES25) which is an octalink design.

This article from Park Tool (http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/crank-removal-installation-isis-drive-or-octalink) explains the removal of octalink cranksets.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to remove the chain ring then a simple Allen wrench
They are typically 5 mm

[Hex key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_key)

If they spin then use a flat head screw driver on the the other end but they typically do not spin.  There are also chain ring wrenches for the other side if a flat head screw driver does not work.  And can use a 10 mm wench on other side but too much to describe - look it up on youtube.

Be careful as most likely it will have spacers you need to save and put back in.

And align the nub on chain-ring with the crank arm.

Torque it back down in a cross pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Front chainrings are not called cassette. They are reffered to as chainrings and cranks.

You will need a hex key and a special too called crank extractor (or crank puller).

Your posted eBay tool is suitable for "real" cassette only. You may need also a tool called chain whip for that.